# Best way to load module that is not used often

Tags: javascript, firebase, express

I have an express script (index.js( in which I load a bunch of api function from other js files.
In one file (text.js) I am exporting a function that tokenizes text that requires the following:

```
const tokenize = require('chinese-tokenizer').loadFile('./cedict_ts.u8');
```

The cedict file is ~10MB.

The question is, when I deploy to firebase and index.js api functions are loaded, is the 10MB file preloaded into memory or is that when an api call occurs then the 10MB file is loaded? Also, if an api call happens that does require a function from text.js, would the 10MB still load into memory?

Basically, I want to figure out if it would be better to put the require call inside the function that tokenizes and not on top of text.js.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#use_dependencies_wisely that and the video right next to it may offer some guidance until a complete answer comes around

Comment: Whenever this code runs for the first time `const tokenize = require('chinese-tokenizer').loadFile('./cedict_ts.u8');` is when these will execute.  You don't show how/where this is placed in your code for us to know anything more about when it runs.  The second time this is called (if there is a second time), the `require('chinese-tokenizer')` will not need to run again because that first result is already cached (all modules are cached when loaded with `require()`, but `.loadFile('./cedict_ts.u8')` will run again.

Comment: If the `cedict` file is ~10MB and you're going to need it eventually, then you may as well load it once at server startup time and then make sure you are reusing the value from that first time and not loading it over and over again.  If you may never need it, then you can load it upon demand the first time (and then save that result), but since `require()` is synchronous and it appears that `.loadFile()` may also be synchronous, you generally don't want to run that during a live server request because it will be blocking.